# Swift - Alamofire completionhandler

Tags: swift, get, request, alamofire

I am working with Alamofire to retrieve data from a web API:

```
func getData(completionHandler: (responseObject: NSDictionary?) -> ()) -> () {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://example.com/api/resource/")
        .validate()
        .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
        .responseJSON { (request, response, responseObject) in

            switch responseObject {
                case .Success:
                    print("Validation Successful")
                    completionHandler(responseObject: responseObject as? NSDictionary)
                case .Failure(_, let error):
                    print(error)
            }

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getData { (str, error) in
        if str != nil {
            print(str)
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, it gives an error, the error is shown below

```
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

I don't know what is wrong with it and how to fix it.
Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `getData` incorrectly. You are passing the completion handler two parameters `(str, error` when it only takes a single `responseObject`.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem while using Alamofire once. I deleted and reimported framework and then it worked. Looked like the compiler had some problem with that.

Anyway try to `Product > Clean` your project also.

If it still doesn't work try to set `breakpoints` (or simply comment) your nested section to spot where is exactly the failure.